# Setting dynamic paging to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview, paging

There is a small advancement in my app, developing using ASP.Net and C# on fx4.0. Requirement is that my client needs dynamic paging size. He wants to set page size of all gridviews approx 10-15 , as needed. If he wants 5 then my app will display 5 and if he sets 10 then the app will display 10.

Please help me. I have added skin for gridview. Do it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can Override AllowPaging and PageSize set in skin file
please refer http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/487895-overriding-allowpaging-pagesize-set-skin-file.

something like
table caption {
background-color: #5D7B9D;
color: White;
font-size: 16pt;
}